# Collect changing/dynamic variable from batch, and transfer to C# (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, batch-file, cmd

So I am writing a simple batch program that will just search for the specified file:

```
@echo off
del temp1.txt
del temp2.txt
set curfile=0
set percentage=0
set numfiles=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%n in ('dir %searchfor% /b /s') do set numfiles=%numfiles%+1
for /f "tokens=*" %%n in ('dir %searchfor% /b /s') do (
    set /a "rand=%random% % 10"
    set /a "rand=rand*1000"
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w %rand%> nul
    set curfile=%curfile%+1
    set percentage=%curfile%*100
    set percentage=%percentage%/%numfiles%
    set p=%%n
if defined p (
echo %p% >>temp1.txt
echo %percentage% >>temp2.txt
echo %numfiles% >>temp3.txt
))
```

So I am not familiar with C# at all, but it seems fairly intuitive. My goal is to create a C# based UI for this, that can do these tasks:

- Run the batch script (let's call the batch searchr.bat)
- As the batch file is searching through files, and updating the variables to gives us these values:

  ```
   The filepath of the file it found (defined as %%n and %p%)
   The percentage complete of the search through files
   The total number of files on the computer
  ```
- Our C# program to collect these variables and have access to them, and update the variables as the corresponding files update.

So essentially I want to have my C# program running, and the batch at the same time, and the C# reading the outputs of the batch file live, as they update.

I tried to keep the batch file as intuitive as possible, there are some stuff I just didn't care to polish or optimize.

Answer (score 0):

why not in pure batch?

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem your search mask
set "searchfor=*.*"

rem needed to show progress
set/a curfile=0, percentage=0, numfiles=0
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%a"
for /L %%i in (1,1,39) do set "DEL_LINE=!DEL_LINE!!DEL!!DEL!"

rem get file number
for /f "tokens=*" %%n in ('dir /a-d-s-h /b "%searchfor%" ^| find /v /c ""') do set "numfiles=%%n" & echo/Processing folder %%~dpn&echo/

::now do work
for /f "tokens=*" %%n in ('dir /a-d-s-h /b "%searchfor%"') do (
  set/a curfile+=1, percentage=curfile*100/%numfiles%
  <NUL set/P=!DEL_LINE!Processing !curfile! of %numfiles%, !percentage!%%. %%~nxn
  rem ...
  rem your code here
  rem ...
  ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 500> nul
)
echo/&echo/Done.

EndLocal
exit/B
```